# Pjsip Android, PJSIP_INV_STATE_EARLY state for call never set. When I should do it?

Tags: android, voip, pjsip

I'm trying to check call state:

```
    public void onCallState(OnCallStateParam prm) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCallState: CallState changing");
    CallInfo ci = null;
    try {
        ci = getInfo();
        pjsip_inv_state state = ci.getState();




        if (state == pjsip_inv_state.PJSIP_INV_STATE_EARLY) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CallState changed: PJSIP_INV_STATE_EARLY");
            listener.onCallStateChanged(VoipCallState.EARLY);
        }
....
```

But this if statement is not calling never.
Is it my mistake?

Comment: Same problem too! I haven't states EARLY, TRYING, etc... Only CONNECTED and DISCONNECTED!